# When I tell my Python program to run, it just sits there

Tags: python-3.x

My program is:

```
def start():
choice = 0
print("You see a dark cave ahead, and a castle in the distance")
while choice == 0:
  print("OPTIONS: CAVE; CASTLE")
  x = str(input())
  if x.lower() == "cave":
    cave()
    choice = 1
  elif x.lower() == "castle":
    castle()
    choice = 1
  else:
    print("That is not an option. Please try again")
```

when I run it, it just sits there and doesn't do anything. I can't find anything wrong with it. Any tips?

Comment: do you run the `start()` function?

Comment: please upload a [MCVE] and explain how you test your program.